# Where does the iCloud saves documents on the PC?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I Want to sync my app docs with a PC via the iCloud and for that i need the desktop application to be able to get synced with the iCloud.

Could this be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the PC, as in Windows PC's?

As far as I know, iCloud and it's associated API's only work with iOS 5 and Mac OS 10.7

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php

If you meant MacOS, the documentation for it can be found at:

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/

Comment: the Control Panel may be available for Windows but only Apple-authored apps using a private framework or library would able to sync things up to iCloud.

Comment: I remember that, on the WWDC, the guy giving the general talk on iCloud said something about Windows APIs, so perhaps best to have a look at that video to see what exactly is possible. Sorry I can't be more precise, but I couldn't find a link.